# Changes to the amygdala due to PTSD

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, fear, ptsd

The one thing I have often heard regarding changes in the brain due to trauma and PTSD is that the amygdala is enlarged (e.g. [Kuo et al, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1001/archgenpsychiatry.2012.73)). This is understandable considering the amygdala is responsible for the fear response.

However, looking more into changes in the brain, there are contradicting reports of smaller amygdala (e.g. [Rogers, et al. 2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pscychresns.2009.06.001)). What is the current concensus on this?

### References

Kuo, J. R., Kaloupek, D. G., & Woodward, S. H. (2012). Amygdala volume in combat-exposed veterans with and without posttraumatic stress disorder: a cross-sectional study. *Archives of general psychiatry, 69*(10), 1080-1086. https://doi.org/10.1001/archgenpsychiatry.2012.73

Rogers, M. A., Yamasue, H., Abe, O., Yamada, H., Ohtani, T., Iwanami, A., ... & Kasai, K. (2009). Smaller amygdala volume and reduced anterior cingulate gray matter density associated with history of post-traumatic stress disorder. *Psychiatry Research: Neuroimaging, 174*(3), 210-216. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pscychresns.2009.06.001